# What are silver doors and objects?

Tags: lego-pirates-of-the-caribbean

In LEGO Pirates of the Caribbean, what are the silver doors and objects? How do I get past them/interact with them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use explosives to destroy them. You may not have a character with explosives yet, but you'll unlock them later. The general rule of thumb for Lego Games is that you can't do everything in a level in story mode, you need to wait for free play mode and until you unlocked all necessary characters.